# Evento click no me funciona

Tags: jquery, css, eventos

No me funciona el evento `click` para que se agrande el `padding` y cambie el color del borde a rojo, no se que pueda ser.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#amarillo").css("background","yellow");
    $("#azul").css("background","blue");
    $("#rojo").css("background","red");
    $("#verde").css("background","green");
    $(".dashed").css("border","3px dashed black");
    $(".solid").css("border","3px solid black");
    $("p").css("padding","10px");
    var parrafo = $("p")
    parrafo.click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("grande")){
            $(this).removeClass("grande")
        }else{
            $(this).addClass("grande");
        }
    })
});
```

El código creo que esta bien, anteriormente hice un ejercicio parecido pero si me funciona y lo veo tal cual, pero este no:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>practica</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="practica.js"></script>
        <style>
            .grande{
                padding: 20px ;
                border: 5px solid black;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="amarillo"class="dashed">Amarillo</p>
        <p id="azul"class="solid">Azul</p>
        <p id="rojo"class="dashed">Rojo</p>
        <p id="verde"class="solid">Verde</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola Limber. Yo siempre que he tenido que trabajar con eventos onclick, siempre lo he realizado sobre un elemento, no sobre una colección. Puedes intentar hacerlo por cada id o por algún valor de atributo ([attribute=value]). Un saludo

Answer (score 4):

Cambia esta parte del código:

```
var parrafo = $("p")
parrafo.click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("grande")){
        $(this).removeClass("grande")
    }else{
        $(this).addClass("grande");
    }
})
```

por esta otra:

```
let parrafos = document.getElementsByTagName('p'); // selecciona elementos conn tag <p>
        Array.from(parrafos).forEach( parrafo => { //recorre los elementos con forEach
                parrafo.addEventListener("click", () =>{ 
                parrafo.classList.toggle('grande'); // con classList.toggle se quita o se pone la clase .grande según este presente o no
            });
        });
```

Puedes ahorrarte los bloques de if() y usar classList.toggle para alternar una clase.

Por qué el código que te paso no usa jQuery?, nada, preferencia personal, jQuery esta ok, pero me divierte más el js vanilla :).

El código js vanilla es soportado por jquery, así que puedes combinar a tu conveniencia. Espero te sirva, saludos.

ejemplo funcionando en : https://jsfiddle.net/s8zgwa2p/

Answer (score 1):

Modifiqué tu código para hacerlo funcionar.

1. Básicamente separé el código `CSS` e inicialicé el `padding` de la etiqueta `<p>` en **10px** desde le inicio.
2. Veo que tus funciones de `jQuery` van en un archivo separado... Te recomiendo mover la etiqueta `<script>` al final de la página, justo antes de cerrar la etiqueta `<body>`. Sin embargo, la etiqueta que importa la librería `jQuery`, déjala en el `<head>`.
3. En el código `jQuery`, puedes usar [el método .on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) para controlar el evento `click` y usar [el método toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) para agregar o remover la clase cada vez que se haga click sobre el párrafo.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#amarillo").css("background", "yellow");
  $("#azul").css("background", "blue");
  $("#rojo").css("background", "red");
  $("#verde").css("background", "green");
  $(".dashed").css("border", "3px dashed black");
  $(".solid").css("border", "3px solid black");
  $("p").on('click', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("grande");
  })
});
```

```css
.grande {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}

p {
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>practica</title>
  <!--script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.6.4.min.js"></script-->
</head>

<body>
  <p id="amarillo" class="dashed">Amarillo</p>
  <p id="azul" class="solid">Azul</p>
  <p id="rojo" class="dashed">Rojo</p>
  <p id="verde" class="solid">Verde</p>
  <!--script type="text/javascript" src="practica.js"></script-->
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Estás diciendo por dos sitios diferentes como tiene que ser padding y border, con jquery se las estás poniendo directamente al elemento lo que tiene preferencia sobre las clases en style.
Ya que eso es lo que modifica .grande yo crearía otra clase .peq donde estaría el estilo que le pones a p. Una vez creada solo tendrías que alternar entre una y otra:

```
.peq{padding:10px}
```

Para controlar el borde una opción sería poner !important en grande para que tenga preferencia el borde de .grande aunque yo preferiría diseñar bien los estilos desde el principio y no ponerlos con jquery

```
.grande {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 5px solid black!important;
}
```